# Why is it not correctly increasing a integer from json?

Tags: python, json, discord

I wan´t to make a levelsystem for my discord bot. When a user joins the server. The bot creates correctly a new json item in a json file, but when it comes to increase the exp from the user the bot wont add the amount correctly and sometimes it creates a new json input with an different userid.

The json file `users_level.json`:

```
{
}
```

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open("./data/users_level.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member)

        with open("./data/users_level.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("./data/users_level.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            await update_data(users, message.author)
            number = random.randint(5, 10)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, number)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

        with open("./data/users_level.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id]["level"] = 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]["experience"] += exp


async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await channel.send(f":tada: Congrats {user.mention}, you levelled up to level {lvl_end}!")
        users[user.id]["level"] = lvl_end
```

This is how the json file is looking after sending some messages with the same account:

```
{"676573403230240813": {"experience": 9, "level": 1}, "676573403230240813": {"experience": 10, "level": 1}}
```

Comment: "sometimes"? Have you tried figuring out what condition triggers that behavior?

Comment: i have no idea but when you send the first message, it give you exp to your userid id in the json list. at the second message it creates an new item in the json list with the same userid and with 0 exp. at the third message both userid which are the same have 5 exp and up then the next message doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies with `user.id`. JSON keys always end up as strings; thus when loaded as a Python dictionary, the keys will be of type `str`. Contrary to this, `user.id` is an `int`.

To solve this, simply cast all `user.id` to `str` before accessing the `users` dictionary.

Example:

```py
async def update_data(users, user):
    uid = str(user.id)
    if not uid in users:
        users[uid] = {}
        users[uid]["experience"] = 0
        users[uid]["level"] = 1
```